# Stacked barplot with repeated colors by value and fixed length for each bin

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a DataFrame with 10 columns and three values {0,1,2}:

```
row1 = [random.randint(0,2) for i in range(10)]
row2 = [random.randint(0,2) for i in range(10)]
df = pd.DataFrame([{i:row1[i] for i in range(10)}, {i:row2[i] for i in range(10)}])
```

I want to plot these values in a horizonal barplot, where each value should have another color, but the same width.

**First try**

```
df.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, legend=False)
```

[image: first try]

ok, so here the width of each stacked value is not fixed. So I thought of a helper Dataframe which fixes the width to one:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([{i:1 for i in range(10)}, {i:1 for i in range(10)}])
```

[image: second try]

ok, perfect, each stacked column has the same width, but now I want the colors to be either grey, blue or red, according to the values in `df`

1. How do I do that?
2. Is there a better way to generate such a plot?
3. Is there a specific name for such a plot?
4. Instead of fixed colors per value, is it possible to use a color scale?
5. Bonus: Is there a way to frame each bin? So that if two bins (columns in a row) have the same value next to each other,  you can still see these are two separate datapoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are searching for `plt.imshow` or `sns.heatmap` rather than stack barplot. For example:

```
sns.heatmap(df, cmap='tab10', linewidths=1, linecolor='w')
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to have it in the look of a bar plot?

Comment: Maybe setting `linewidths=0`?